# C++ Inheritance Dimension Calculator program error: "function call missing argument list"

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, error-handling

I'm making a program in my programming class for homework involving inheritance that calculates a distance between one, two and three dimensions. Basically If the User chooses to calculate in one dimension, It should make a calculation (x) on a number line. If the user chooses two dimensions, The user enters a pair of (x,y) coordinates like a XY Cartesian coordinate plane, to which the distance is calculated between the two points. If the user chooses a 3 dimension calculation, the user should enter a pair of x,y,and z coordinates to which it also should calculate the distance between the two. However the problem that I am currently having is that I am getting a total of 18 various types of errors in my function definitions mostly coming from stating that the function call does not match the argument list. Is there a way to explain these simply and give me an idea on how to solve my error(s)? Here is my code, first staring with my one dimension definition, then the two dimension definition, the three dimension definition and finally my main. The lines with errors have been Added properly. Thanks.

```
//definition of 1st dimension
#include <iostream>
#include "OneDimenson.h"
OneDimension::OneDimension(int x) 
{   //sets x
    x = x;
}
int OneDimension::GetX()
{   // returns x
    return x;
}
int OneDimension::CalcDistance(OneDimension point2)
{   //calculates the distance between the instance(object created) and the 1d point
    int distance = 0;
    distance = point2.GetX - x; //2 ERRORS HERE: 1.) Function doesent match
    // argument list and 2.) illegal, left operand has type int.
    cout << "Distance Calculated." << endl;
    return distance;
}
// definition of 2nd definiton
#include <iostream>
#include "OneDimenson.h"
#include "TwoDimension.h"
TwoDimension::TwoDimension(int x, int y):OneDimension(x)
{   // sets x and y
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
int TwoDimension::GetY()
{   // returns y
    return y;
}
int TwoDimension::CalcDistance(OneDimension point2)
{   // calculates the distance between the 2nd distance and the 1d point.
    int distance = 0;
    distance = point2.GetX - x; // 2 ERRORS: 1.) function call missing from 
    // arguement. 2.) illegal, left operand has a type of int.
    return distance;
}
int TwoDimension::CalcDistance(TwoDimension point2)
{   // calculates the distance between the instance and the 2nd point.
    int distance = 0;
    distance = point2.GetY - x; //ERROR HERE
    return distance;
}
// definition of the 3d dimension
#include "OneDimenson.h"
#include "TwoDimension.h"
#include "ThreeDimension.h"
ThreeDimension::ThreeDimension(int x, int y, int z):TwoDimension(x,y)
{   //sets x, y, and z
    cout << "please set the dimension for x." << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "please set the dimension for y." << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "please set the dimension for z." << endl;
    cin >> z;
}
int ThreeDimension::GetZ()
{   //returns z
    return z;
}
int ThreeDimension::CalcDistance(OneDimension point2)
{   // calculates the distance between the 3d instance and the 1d point.
    int distance = 0;
    distance = point2.GetX - z; //2 Errors: 1.) Function doesent match
    // argument list and 2.) illegal operand has type int.
    return distance;
}
int ThreeDimension::CalcDistance(TwoDimension point2)
{   // calculates the distance between the 2d instance and the 2d point.
    int distance = 0;
    distance = point2.GetY - y; //2 ERRORS: 1) Function call missing from
    // arguement. 2) illegal, left operand has a type of int.
    return distance;
}
int ThreeDimension::CalcDistance(ThreeDimension point2)
{   // calculates the distance between the instance and the 3d point.
    int distance = 0;
    distance = point2.GetZ - x; //2 ERRORS: 1) Function call missing from 
    // arguement and 2) illegal, left operand has type of int
    return distance;
}
// This is the main
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "OneDimenson.h"
#include "TwoDimension.h"
#include "ThreeDimension.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int UserChoice = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int point2 = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "-----CONSOLE MENU----" << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to calculate 1d, 2d or 3d?" << endl;
        cout << "(PRESSING 0 ENDS PROGRAM)." << endl;
        cout << "1.) 1d calculation" << endl;
        cout << "2.) 2d calculation" << endl;
        cout << "3.) 3d calculation" << endl;
        cin >> UserChoice;
        switch (UserChoice)
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            // if user selects 1, then the user selects x, then point 2, to which the distance is calculated.
            cout << "1d calculation chosen. Enter the x point: " << endl;
            cin >> x;
            OneDimension OneDimension(x);
            cout << "Enter the instance Point: " << endl;
            cin >> point2;
            cout << "The distance between the two points (in 1d space) is: " << OneDimension.CalcDistance(point2);
            cout << " " << endl;
        case 2: // ERROR: ONE DIMENSION IS SKIPPED BY CASE LABEL
            //  if user selects 2, the user then selects the x and y coordinate. then the distance is calculated.
            cout << "2d calculation chosen. Enter the x part of the point: " << endl;
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter the y part of the point." << endl;
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Enter the instance point." << endl;
            cin >> point2;
            TwoDimension TwoDimension(x,y);
            cout << "The distance between the two points (in 2d space) is: " << TwoDimension.CalcDistance(point2);
            cout << " " << endl;
        case 3: //ERROR: TWO DIMESION AND ONE DIMENSION ARE SKIPPED BY CASE LABEL:
            // if user selects 3, then the user selects x, y and z coordinate. Then the distance is calculated.
            cout << "3d calculation chosen. Enter the x part of the point: " << endl;
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter the y part of the point." << endl;
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Enter the z part of the point." << endl;
            cin >> z;
            cout << "Enter the instance point." << endl;
            cin >> point2;
            ThreeDimension ThreeDimension(x, y, z);
            cout << "The distance between the two points (in 3d space) is: " << ThreeDimension.CalcDistance(point2);
            cout << " " << endl;
        default: //ERROR ABOUT HOW ONEDIMENSION, TWODIMENSION, AND THREEDIMENSION ARE SKIPPED BY DEFAULT LABEL
            break;
        }
    } while (UserChoice != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should list the errors you have. Although an error about wrong arguments to a function is almost always pretty straightforward.

Comment: "the problem that I am currently having is that I am getting a total of 18 errors in my function definitions stating that the function call does not match the argument list." And those errors are...? Copy them here! Including the line number, and even better, mark the line in the code that gives you an error!

Comment: I don't know why I keep seeing people implement classes in `main.cpp` that were defined in their own header. The problem is, you have a function that accepts a `OneDimension`, `TwoDimension`, or `ThreeDimension`, and you pass it a single integer.

Comment: Whops! I just now realized that.. Im working on editing it now. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
OneDimension.CalcDistance(point2);
```

You are passing it point2 which is of type int. However, at the place you define the function

```
OneDimension::CalcDistance(OneDimension point)
```

You specify that the function parameter should be of type OneDimension. Since the types do not match, this generates the errors. You have the same problem with TwoDimension and ThreeDimension.

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong, but what your saying basically is instead of point 2 being declared as an int, I have to pass it as an object of type OneDimension?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The function definition syntax `OneDimension::CalcDistance(OneDimension point)` defines the function, it specifies what the function is called and how to use it. Here it means that "The function CalcDistance accepts a single parameter of type OneDimension." The parameter description is the part between the ( ).